# Extract video frames in python using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-processing

I want to break my video into frames.

I am using the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myvideo.mp4')
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)

try:
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')

currentFrame = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
    name = './data/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
    print ('Creating...' + name)
    cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

    # To stop duplicate images
    currentFrame += 1
    if not ret: break


# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have set the FPS = 5 and 'myvideo.mp4' is 0:55 sec long. So, I'd expect to have 55*5 = 275 frames, but the code above gives me a lot more frames and it doesn't stop generating frames. Is something wrong in the code?

Comment: `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)` is used for capturing video from a camera, were you can control the framerate. The command has no affect when reading frames from a video file. You can skip frames - save every 5'th frame for example. For example: `if currentFrame % 5 == 0:` `cv2.imwrite`... Note: Move `if not ret: break` to be right after `ret, frame = cap.read()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a proper framerate you can do

```
framerate = vid.get(5)
```

instead of

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 5)
```

this will give you the exact framerate

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Chewie is correct to be sure that where you should put that line you could follow this code:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

interval = int(fps / 2) 
frame_count = 0
while True:
    # Read the current frame
    ret, frame = video.read()
    video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_count + interval)
    frame_count += interval
```